# Using Carto.js with free account?

Tags: carto, carto-js, pricing

I have a website running with an old CartoDB account and I would like to make some improvements.

With the arrival of CARTO BUILDER, I lost the opportunity to share layers and thus be able to use carto.js

I understand when reading carto.js 4.0 that it is no longer possible to use it with a free account, since you need an API key to use it, but I am not sure.

Can anyone confirm me this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the on-topic page of the [Help] says "We are not a formal GIS Software Support Site and are likely to close questions and recommend you seek official routes for support if you ... ask about licensing, pricing and/or release dates"

Answer (score 1):

You can use CARTO.js with a free account and public datasets, just put any string in the API key parameter. If you check any of the [examples](https://carto.com/documentation/cartojs/examples/) from the documentation you'll see that for the API key parameter a dumb `YOUR_API_KEY` value is passed.

Mind that CARTO.js v4 is not officially released, and there will be also changes in ENGINE with a new authorization API, but at this moment not much more detail can be provided.

Comment: Jorge, just tried and works great!
Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Excellent, please mark the question then as resolved ☺️